# Neo4j creating a graph database

Tags: neo4j

```
package com;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;


public class hotspots {
public static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
{
    PERSON
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphDatabaseService graphdb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("target/dbnew");
    Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx();

    try{
        Node n1 = graphdb.createNode();
        Node n2 = graphdb.createNode();

        n1.setProperty("name","Melwin");
        n2.setProperty("name","Louis");

Relationship rel1 =      graphdb.getReferenceNode().createRelationshipTo( n1, RelTypes.PERSON );
Relationship rel2 = graphdb.getReferenceNode().createRelationshipTo( n2,  RelTypes.PERSON );

        tx.success();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        tx.failure();
    }
    finally{
        tx.finish();
    }

    graphdb.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Success");
}


}
```

This is a small database that I created, and I view it in Neoclipse. Each time I run this code and view it in Neoclipse I get double the nodes and relationships. In other words, I get two more nodes with the same name & relationship.

Comment: I can't see the problem here. The only thing I see is that you cannot be sure that the database is empty when you create the EmbeddedGraphDatabase object.
Maybe you lunched this code two times ?

Answer (score 2):

Just creating new nodes with the same properties that other nodes that already exists in the database will create duplicates. The same goes for relationships. If you're importing data then do that once and only once, or your import code will have to be create-if-not-already-exists "aware", in that before checking if a node exists check with an index and before creating a relationship check if that already exist by iterating through them for that node.

Comment: oh ok...i get it now...bt how do u check if a node or relationship exists with an index...i dono the procedure...